# What was the international (not American) opinion of the 1984 Nicaraguan Election?

Tags: election, 1980s, central-america

The Reagan administration obviously condemned it as a "Soviet sham," which ramped up tensions and aid to the Contras.

What were the opinions of the international community? What did human rights organizations and the United Nations think about the legitimacy of the election?

Was the majority opinion that it was a free and open election or that it was hostile and rigged?

Comment: From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_Nicaraguan_general_election): "_The Reagan administration denounced the 1984 vote as a 'Soviet-style sham', **despite contrary opinions from external observers such as Baron Chitnis, the Latin American Studies Association, and the international press**_."  The article includes linked sources.

Comment: @sempaiscuba There is exactly one linked source in reference to the international opinion on its freedom. A link that is no longer working. 

Wikipedia saying that the international press differed from the American opinion isn't at all impressive to me unless it's backed up, which it isn't. I assume this to be true regardless from other readings, but I'd like references. The Wikipedia article is short with many dead links and poor references.

Comment: Typing the title of the source into Google gives multiple copies, including [this one](https://lasaweb.org/uploads/reports/electoralprocessnicaragua.pdf).  Beyond that, the sources listed in the bibliography seem to cover the topic fairly well.